# join two sql table and and set session using the table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a booking system, I have a table for user to log in, another table for advocate login and another table for booking information. I want data entered from user to be displayed to a specific advocate. I have tried using SQL JOIN but it is not displaying any information.

MY TABLES

```
advocate
bookingcalendar
```

here is the SQL code

```
$sql = ("SELECT bookingcalendar.*,advocate.userName, FROM bookingcalendar JOIN advocate ON bookingcalendar.*=advocate.userName WHERE $current_epoch BETWEEN start_day AND end_day");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: `bookingcalendar.*=advocate.userName` part is not correct. Does `advocate.userName` equals to all fields in `bookingcalendar`

Comment: `bookingcalendar.* = ` need to be `bookingcalendar.<provide some column name to comapre> = `

Comment: @efg (my I call you hij?) would you be so kind and share something more than only your table names?

Answer (score 0):

`bookingcalendar.*=advocate.userName` part is incorrect use `bookingcalendar.Column_name` where `Column_name` is common on both the table bookingcalendar and advocate which may be `userName` in your case

```
SELECT bookingcalendar.*,advocate.userName
FROM bookingcalendar JOIN advocate 
ON bookingcalendar.userName = advocate.userName 
WHERE $current_epoch BETWEEN start_day AND end_day
```

Comment: I would expect bookingcalender to contain the advocate id, but your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: thanks for your prompt answer, though it did no work well with me..let me do some clarification...

Comment: what i wanted is if i can ON to set sessions between the advocate table and the  bookingcalendar table

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a field that is in common between your two tables as the key to the join condition. For example, with some kind of `userID` :

`SELECT bookingcalendar.*, advocate.userName
FROM bookingcalendar
JOIN advocate ON bookingcalendar.userID=advocate.userID
WHERE $current_epoch BETWEEN start_day AND end_day`

I advise you to **not use the userName as the key** to join your two tables, because multiple users can eventually have the same `userName`, and the join on two strings takes more time than the join on two numbers.

That is not just an advice to take lightly. You absolutely should join your tables on some numerical ID instead of a user name.

-- EDIT --

Actually, I don't really know what an "advocate" is, so maybe your join key shouldn't even be some user id/name. To know that, I need to better understand the relationship between `advocate`, `user` and `bookingCalendar`. Maybe a description of their columns could help us answer this hidden part of the question.